# Issues creating gMSA on domain controller

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-server-2012-r2

I am having issues creating a group managed service account (gMSA) via PowerShell in the domain controller in my environment. This issue only started happening in August and wasn’t happening before.

This is the command that I am trying to run in PowerShell:

`$allowedPrincipals = @("ServerGroup1", "ServerGroup2")`

`New-ADServiceAccount -name mymsa -DNSHostName mymsa.myenv.com -PrincipalsAllowedToRetrieveManagedPassword $allowedPrincipals`

And this is the error that I'm getting :

> New-ADServiceAccount : There are no more endpoints available from the endpoint mapper
> At line:2 char:1
> New-ADServiceAccount -name mymsa -DNSHostName mymsa...
> + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (CN=mymsa...d,DC=govt,DC=nz:String) [New-ADServiceAccount], ADException
> + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:1753,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.NewADServiceAccount `

I've tried basically of the fixes I can find online, but none of the resources online are trying the same thing as I am (creating a gMSA). Would appreciate any advice

Comment: Check what type of object can be passes as **PrincipalsAllowedToRetrieveManagedPassword** parameter - [PrincipalsAllowedToRetrieveManagedPassword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/new-adserviceaccount?view=windowsserver2022-ps#-principalsallowedtoretrievemanagedpassword)

Comment: @Pulkownik that's not the issue as I was using the same principals to create gMSAs a few months ago and it was working fine

Comment: Have you check this one [replication issue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-ds/manage/replication-error-1753-there-are-no-more-endpoints-available-from-the-endpoint-mapper)